# Trying to refer multiple elements from an array that is inside an object

Tags: arrays, object

I have this object that has an array with multiple objects and arrays.
I have been trying to figure out how to refer to multiple elements at once but cannot find the way.

```
  var questions =  {
  options : [{
  question : "Only one province is oficially bilingual, can you guess which 
  one?",
  choices : ["Quebec", "British Columbia", "Manitoba", "Newbrunswick"],
  answer : 3
  },

  {  question : "Which canadian city is considered The Hollywood North?",
  choices : ["Manitoba", "Vancouver", "Beamsville", "Niagara Falls",],
  answer : 1
  },

  {  question : "What is the capital of Canada?",
  choices : ["Ottawa", "Toronto", "Vancouver", "Edmonton"],
  answer : 0
  },

  {  question : "What are the official winter and summer sports of Canada?",
  choices : ["Ice hockey and lacrosse", "Boxing and Baseball", "Skiing and 
  Swimming", "Football and Tennis"],
  answer : 0
  },

  {  question : "How many time zones does Canada Have?",
  choices : ["4", "3", "5", "6"],
  answer : 3
  },

  {  question : "What animal is on the Canadian quarter?",
  choices : ["Whale", "Polar Bear", "Caribou", "Beaver"],
  answer : 2
  },

  {  question : "What is the Canadian $1 coin called?",
  choices : ["Moonie", "Dolly", "Loonie", "Toonie"],
  answer : 2
  },

  {  question : "What is the leader of Canada called?",
  choices : ["Queen", "Prime Minister", "King", "President"],
  answer : 1
  },

  {  question : "What is the name of the highest mountain in Canada?",
   choices : ["Mount Logan", "Mount Carleton", "Mount Saint Elias", "Mount 
  Columbia"],
  answer : 0
  }
  ]};
```

I have tried:

```
   console.log(questions.options[0].question);
   console.log(questions.options[1].question);
   console.log(questions.options[2].question);  
   //etc...
```

Is there any way I can have all the questions displayed from one console.log? I guess a for loop would do it, but I'm not able to figure out. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like :

```
questions.options.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(question.question);
});
```

or if you want only one string which refer to all items :

```
var allQuestions = questions.options.reduce(function(all, current) { 
    return all + ' - ' + current;
})
```